# How to build stream controller to listen to onAuthStateChanged for Firebase Authentication?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

This might be a noob question, but I am trying to add some functionalities on top of the classic Firebase Authentication flow in Flutter (here is an [example](https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/super-simple-authentication-flow-with-flutter-firebase-737bba04924c)). I have the below stream to get Firebase User instances as the user logs in / out which I convert to my app's User model.

```
 // auth changes user stream
Stream<User> get user {

  return _auth.onAuthStateChanged
    .map((FirebaseUser user) => User(uid: user.uid));
}
```

This all nice and well, but since a Firebase User has very limited properties, I need to fetch additional user data. I do that in an async Firestore query which returns a User instance with more properties filled.

**My problem is that I am having a hard time understand how I could build a stream controller on top of the stream above** in order to add the results of my async query so that my stream makes the User instance with all the properties filled available to the rest of the app.

Thanks in advance! Also, if anyone has suggestions as to how to grab this additional user past login, I'd be curious to hear what best practices look like :)

Comment: What does "build a stream controller on top of the stream above" mean?

Comment: @Kahou, this might not be well expressed, but I know that a stream controller can let you add to a given streak via something like: streamController.sink.add(). Once my updated User data is added to that sink, I'd be able to get it in my listeners.

Answer (score 0):

Using `StreamTransformer`

```
  var userTransformer = StreamTransformer<FirebaseUser, User>.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (value, sink) => sink.add(User(uid: value.uid)),
  );
```

```
Stream<User> get user {
  return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.transform(userTransformer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kahou! I am going to look into StreamTransformers and check out your strategy. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what Kahou proposed, here is a solution with a StreamTransformer:

```
  // create stream transformer to modify onAuthStateChanged
  StreamTransformer getOtherUserInfo() => StreamTransformer<User, User>.fromHandlers(handleData:
    (user, sink) async {
      if (user == null) {

      } else {
        User appUser = await _getUserDetailsAsync(user);
        sink.add(appUser);
      }
    }
  );
```

I use _getUserDetailsAsync to get more user data from Firestore...

then I just add the StreamTransformer to original stream:

```
  // auth changes user stream
  Stream<User> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged
      .map((FirebaseUser user) => User(uid: user.uid))
      .transform(getOtherUserInfo());
  }
```